# Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_id() when installing

Tags: opencart, freebsd, opencart2.x

I've installed *opencart* version 2.2.0.0 in a FreeBSD server 10.3-RELEASE-p3.  Followed the installation instructions for Linux of the `install.txt` file.

In step 5, *Visit the store homepage e.g. http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/store/*, what I get in response is a Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_id() in /usr/local/www/opencart/system/library/session.php on line 23
```

This happens when installing both from the FreeBSD package and also from source.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't have *session* PHP extension.
Try to run:

> php -m | grep session

In case empty output, install php-session extension via pkg or ports tree.

Comment: That's it, but not only it.  As  I installed `php-fpm` in a different jail, I had much less `php` modules installed, 20 vs 39 that were installed in the other jail containing the `opencart` package.  So, for `session` module, as well for the other 18 modules, I just have to find the right package to install in the `php-fpm` jail, so that I have all the required modules installed.